# Am I not a Muslim if I fear snakes?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, kufr

So I came across a Hadith regarding which I have a question
[Sunan Abi Dawud 5350](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:5250) says

> Narrated Abdullah ibn Abbas:
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: He who leaves the snakes along through fear of their pursuit, does not belong to us. We have not made peace with them since we have fought with them.

I have a natural fear of snakes. Does it mean I am not worthy of being called a Muslim? I can’t really take this instinct out of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fearing snakes is not one of the things that take a person out of Islam. Things that take a person out of Islam are mainly kufr and shirk. Neither of which are present in this except if your fear of snakes somehow outweighs your fear of Allah (which is ridiculous).

As for the phrase by the Prophet (SAW) "he does not belong to us," that doesn't necessarily entail that a person is not a Muslim.

It simply shows the importance and severity of the issue, such that if you do it, you are not following the example of the Prophet and companions. It does not mean you aren't Muslim. Generally speaking, sins do not take a person out of Islam.